# Windows form always on top not working c#

Tags: c#, windows, forms, topmost

I searched the forum but still no answers seems to be the right one.

I need to show a message notification from a systray app while users are operating in a browser.

I want this notification to be displayed on top of everything but even if I set it to be TopMost or TopLevel or BringToFront or Focus there's no way I can achieve what I want.

I'm using a simple windows Form and I show it using ShowDialog from the systray app.

Please help me :)

PS: if I launch the notification form from systray app with no other application opened or focused it works fine, I just can't show it in front of the active browser window

Comment: If TopMost isn't working you could try using SetForeGroundWindow in the Win32 APIs

Comment: Just tried but no luck

Comment: The problem is that I show the notification as a dialog from a different thread then the UI one, if I move ShowDialog to the UI thread all's fine but in this way I'm blocking user interaction... :(

Answer (score 0):

```
NameOfYourWindow myTopForm = new NameOfYourWindow();

myTopForm.Owner = App.Current.MainWindow;
myTopForm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
myTopForm.TopMost = true;
myTopForm.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Doesn't work, my owner should be the browser application which is open full screen

Answer (score 0):

```
#region SetForegroundWindow
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
    #endregion
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {

            SetForegroundWindow(GetConsoleWindow());
        }
    }
```